# Jquery change not detecting select change rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm running into an issue in jquery where my selected field isn't getting properly checked with jquery `change()`

```
    = select_tag 'selector-email', 
                 options_for_select([['Mailer', 0], ['Invite Student', 1], ['Invite Visitor', 2]])
```

Above is what my html is parsed as and then in jquery i select the id and use its index to find the value.

```
function mailerChange() {
  $("#selector-email").change(function() {
    console.log($('#selector-email')[0].selectedIndex)
  })
}
```

this works completely fine when I try on codepen but for some reason in rails I just get 0 back as a value. Even when I try in console on my webpage. It can find the selector field but it can't tell what's selected properly.

What's going on here is there a valid reason for this?

Comment: Can you post your rendered HTML or a sample codepen ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Snowfiring/pen/skngh  It totally works on codepen

Comment: I've posted an answer, please check if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your codepen, you are defining the handler on DOM ready and your element is added later.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  mailerChange();
})
```

Try event delegation using jQuery **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**,

```
function mailerChange() {
    $(document).on("change","#selector-email",function() {
       console.log($('option:selected',this).index())
    })
}
```

Comment: The issue still remains all I get is 0 :(

Comment: Check the updated answer. Also can your post the rendered html (after rails) by inspecting the html in your question.

Comment: The html in codepen is what I get from inspectin in rails I'll try current answer, works can you explain why?!